# A coat of paint of thickness $0.07$ cm is to be applied uniformly to the faces of a cube of edge $37$ cm. Use differentials...

Tags: calculus

A coat of paint of thickness $0.07$ cm is to be applied uniformly to the faces of a cube of edge $37$ cm. Use differentials to find the approximate amount of paint required for the job, correct to the nearest cubic centimeter.

I got this question on my math homework and I got to

**A'=12x**
**12x*dx=6(x+^x)^2-6(x)2**

What do I do? My final answer was $498$ but the correct one is $575$. The correct equation was 
**3(x)^2*^x**
how do I get to that?

Comment: Please look up how to type your questions. Then explain how you got your answer

Answer (score 2):

Let$ \ s \ $be the edge of the cube.

Thus:

> $$ \ s=37\ cm \ $$

After the paint is applied, the edge of the cube will *change* from$\ 37\ cm $ to $ 37.14\ cm $:

> $$ \ ds=0.14\ cm \ $$

Recall the formula for volume of a cube:

> $$ \ V=s^{3} \ $$

Differentiating, we get:

> $$ \ dV=3s^{2}ds \ $$

"Plugging in":

> $$ \ dV=3(37\ cm)^{2}(0.14\ cm) \ $$

Which gives us:

> $$ \ dV=574.98\ cm^{3} \ $$

Therefore, the volume of the cube *changes* by approximately$ \ 575\ cm^{3} \ $